# Expected value of $X^2$ if $X \sim N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, statistics

What's the expected value of $X^2$ if $X \sim N(0,1)$? I think this should be the expected value of a $\chi^2$ random variable and the expected value of a $\chi^2$ rv is $k$, which is the degrees of freedom. However, I don't know how to calculate the degrees of freedom. Is it $0$ df because there are no parameters that we are free to choose (i.e. $0$ and $1$ are specified already)?

Is this along the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathbb E[X]=0$, we have
$$\mathbb E[X^2]=\mathbb E[X^2] - \mathbb E[X]^2 = \mathsf{Var}(X)=1.$$

Comment: I believe this has a typo. I think you mean $E[X^{2}] = Var[X] + (E[X])^{2}$ = Var[X] + 0 = Var[X] = 1$

Comment: @Auser Since $\mathsf{Var}(X)=\mathbb E[X^2]$ and $\mathbb E[X]=0$ the two expressions are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The $\chi^2 = \chi^2(k)$ distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom is by definition the distribution of the sum $X_1^n + \cdots + X_k^2$ of $k$ i.i.d. standard normal distributions $X_i\sim N(0, 1)$. The case $k = 1$ corresponds to the case you have here. Its expectation value is known to be $k$, but it's not hard to compute the integral
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[N(0, 1)^2] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\; x^2 e^{-x^2/2}
\end{align*}
by hand (and clearly $\chi_2(k) = k\chi_2(1)$). It's also just the variance of $N(0, 1)$, since its expectation value is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way: note that $1 = \text{Var}(X) = E[X^2] - [E(X)]^2 = E[X^2] - 0$.

In general, if $X \sim N(0, 1)$, it can be shown inductively that
$$E[X^{2n}] = (2n - 1)!!.$$

Answer (score 1):

Yet another method is to consider the Moment Generating Function for a random variable $X$ that is $N(0, 1)$. The function is

$$M_x(t) = e^{t^2/2}$$

Getting the $n$th moment corresponds to evaluating the nth derivative of this function at $t=0$. So to get $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$ we have

$$M''(t) = t^2 e^{t^2/2} + e^{t^2/2}$$ and 
$$M''(0) = \mathbb{E}(X^2) = 1 $$

Comment: yes good point!